# Which function works first in two onclick functions

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Let's say i have two onclick functions binded to an element . May i know which element works first ..??

Example :

```
1. elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
                                         //
                                        },false);
2. elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
                                         //
                                        },false);
```

Which one works first ...?? And is there any way to add some code at end of the onclick function ..

Please don't suggest the below answer

```
elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
                                         //
                                         mycode or function name
                                        },false);
```

Because there is a lot of js files and i couldn't find where the first function ends..

Simply , how to add some code or function at the end of onclick event  ?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to test. **[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmzMD/)**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("test");

elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
   elem.innerHTML += "first";                             //
}, false);
elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
     elem.innerHTML += "second";                                       //
}, false);
```

They execute in the order you add them.

Comment: Ok thank you .. What about the answer for my another question ...? One function is in a js file which is loaded under <head> tag and i want to add a function in <script> tag of html file